# NSImage truncated using PDFKit, PDFPage.thumbnail in Swift / Cocoa

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, pdfkit

I'm trying to generate thumbnails for a PDF in a MacOS application using the following:

```
    func fetchThumb(path: String, docNum: Int = 1, pageNum: Int = 1, maxHeight: Int = 250 )->NSImage? {
        
        var thumbnail: NSImage? = nil
        let boxType = PDFDisplayBox.artBox
        
        let pdfUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path, isDirectory: false)
        
        if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: pdfUrl),
           let pdfPage = pdfDocument.page(at: pageNum-1) {
            
            let bounds = pdfPage.bounds(for: boxType)
            let size = bounds.size
            
            let rRatio = size.height / CGFloat(maxHeight)
            let thumbWidth = size.width / rRatio
            let thumbnailSize = CGSize(width: thumbWidth, height: CGFloat(maxHeight))
            
            thumbnail = pdfPage.thumbnail(of: thumbnailSize, for: boxType)
        }
        return thumbnail
    }
```

Which works absolutely fine most of the time but on a few PDFs I get an oddly cropped image:

[image: Art Box]

I've tried to locate some other method for doing it but everything that I find seems to be iOS specific.  I've also tried all 5 of the various PDFDisplayBox modes and with this document they all fail in some manner or another.

[image]

I also noticed that on these documents in the PDFView (on the right) when the actual page is first displayed it's truncated (just like ArtBox) and stretched for a half-second and then re-renders and corrects itself so perhaps there's something more I need to check?  Or even a completely different approach would be fine as long as it's consistent.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: use your own size rather getting bounds from page

Comment: just like 200x200 with trim box

Comment: @zeeshanAhmed - I'm not sure what you mean?  Size isn't really part of what determines the clipping region on the page it only determines the size of the NSImage returned.  PDFDisplayBox is simply an enum and lets PDFKit know what regoin on the page I need?  Or maybe I'm confused...